# How to select non-uniform length strings from within multiple lines

Tags: normal-mode, multiple-lines, selection

Suppose I have this data:

```
import { york1400 } from "./data/york1400";
import { york1430 } from "./data/york1430";
import { york1500 } from "./data/york1500";
import { york1530 } from "./data/york1530";
import { york1600 } from "./data/york1600";
import { york1630 } from "./data/york1630";
import { sanddown1405 } from "./data/sanddown1405";
import { sanddown1435 } from "./data/sanddown1435";
import { sanddown1505 } from "./data/sanddown1505";
import { sanddown1535 } from "./data/sanddown1535";
import { sanddown1605 } from "./data/sanddown1605";
import { sanddown1635 } from "./data/sanddown1635";
import { haydock1410 } from "./data/haydock1410";
import { haydock1440 } from "./data/haydock1440";
import { haydock1510 } from "./data/haydock1510";
import { haydock1540 } from "./data/haydock1540";
import { haydock1610 } from "./data/haydock1610";
import { haydock1640 } from "./data/haydock1640";
import { thirsk1415 } from "./data/thirsk1415";
import { thirsk1445 } from "./data/thirsk1445";
import { thirsk1515 } from "./data/thirsk1515";
import { thirsk1545 } from "./data/thirsk1545";
import { thirsk1615 } from "./data/thirsk1615";
import { thirsk1645 } from "./data/thirsk1645";
```

And I want to grab, as one selection, all the strings within `{}` so I can paste them elsewhere.

I thought I may be able to select all lines and do `:'<,'>norm yi{` but whilst that goes down the list yanking, I am left with just the last string in my register.

Comment: `:h quote_alpha`

Comment: Ok, so it mentions using the `>` in cpoptIons to add a line break. Do I have to do that before I run the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest for me was based on [Matt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/22797/matt)s comment above.

Do the visual selection of the lines and then `:'<,'>norm "Ayi{`

Using the big `A` as a named register appends each selection into the register.

Comment: You probably want to make sure to clear the a register first. The easy way is qaq, but programatically `:let @a = ''` is clearer.

Comment: You can accept your own answer to mark this as resolved.

Comment: If you are using ideavim, you won't be able to do this as it doesn't support `normal` or `norm` command yet.